# multi process multi GPU with tensorflow, windows

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, gpu, cudnn

I'm little bit new with tensor-flow.. so please be gentle with me.. 
I have problem with creating second process that load tensorflow on already working GPU.

the error I get is:

```
\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:392] error retrieving driver version: Permission denied: could not open driver version path for reading: /proc/driver/nvidia/version
\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:352] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
\kernels\conv_ops.cc:532] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

Hardware details :

```
super micro -  4028GR-TRT
8 GPU's 1080 
CUDA: 8 
cudnn: 5.1 
windows: 10 
tensorflow: 0.12.1 / 1.0.1
```

My PC shouldn't be a problem

```
windows 7
gpu 1070
cuda 8
cudnn 5.1 
tensorflow 0.12.1
```

Can someone tell me why on my PC everything is ok but not on the big one(supermicro)?

is this windows / driver issues maybe?

I try to update NVIDIA driver.. no help on that ..

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow is not always good at sharing GPUs with other processes (including other instances of itself!). The typical workaround is to use the `%CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES%` environment variable to prevent the two processes from clashing over the same GPU. For example:

```
C:\>set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
C:\>python tensorflow_program_1.py
```

While in another command prompt you could tell TensorFlow to use a different GPU as follows:

```
C:\>set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
C:\>python tensorflow_program_2.py
```

Comment: Hi mrry, thanks for the answer but in my case that is not helpful
my process doesn't use 100% of the GPU( use ~60%)
so instead of improve my software i just open new process on the same GPU, and hop the low level driver will use as synchronization